# Comparing concated string recieved from serial data in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to read a serial data into a string with is capable of being compared against another string. I am using if (inputString.equals("test")) to test the boolean value but it is always returning as false as THEY ARE EQUAL is never displayed when test is typed in the serial monitor (which does echo back what ever I sent to the arduino). Any ideas? Is concating the string this way adding extra, non-displayed, bytes to the string?

```
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void setup() {
// initialize serial:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {

       if (inputString.equals("test")) {
       Serial.print("THEY ARE EQUAL"); 
    }

    Serial.print(inputString); 
    // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    }

   }

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
  // get the new byte:
  char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
  // add it to the inputString:
  inputString += inChar;
  stringComplete = true;

  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a String.print(inputString) to find out.

Comment: I just added an LCD to the arduino and added an lcd.print(inputString) and the display is showing what I type and nothing more. However, if I send the Arduino the string - test - it still does not return a true value for if (inputString.equals("test")).

Comment: Try startsWith() instead of equals().

Comment: I changed it to (inputString.startsWith("test")) and it still isn't returning true. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you clearing inputString every loop? inputString = "";

Comment: Yeah but I am doing it after it should have completed the (inputString.equals("test")). Serial.print(inputString) works fine as it prints the string I sent the arduino back to the serial monitor. Afterwards it clears it for the next input. serialEvent() happens between loops on the arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow enough time for the serial data to be read.  Add a delay

```
char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
// add it to the inputString:
delay(100);
inputString += inChar;
```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked! Josh, could you explain why I needed that delay if the string seemed to include all of the characters?

Comment: Serial.read doesn't wait for the end of a string.  As soon as it processes everything in the buffer, it returns.  If you want to see it, take out the delay and add Serial.println(inputString) at the end of your serialEvent and see what happens.  Probably a better way to do this is implement an endflag.  If you're only inputting text, you could look for the inclusion of a number at the end of the text that would indicate the end of the line and then proceed with the rest of the code.

Comment: Ahhhh gotcha. So 'test' wasn't my string but instead each letter was populating the string individually. It was just how it was showing up on the screen because it was processing the input 4 times. With the delay and a println the string is complete. Thanks!!